# Determine the number of authors appearing before "et al." (apacite)

Tags: bibtex, citing, apacite

I'm using the `apacite` package, with the `natbibapa` option set. When I reference a source with more than two authors, two names are printed before "et al." instead of one.

Eg: bibentry:

```
@article{
vlangsocrev,
title = "The psychology of social dilemmas: A review ",
journal = "Organizational Behavior and Human Decision Processes ",
volume = "120",
number = "2",
pages = "125 - 141",
year = "2013",
doi = "10.1016/j.obhdp.2012.11.003",
author = "Van Lange, Paul AM  and  Joireman, Jeff and Parks,Craig D  
and  Van Dijk, Eric"
}
```

Command: `\citet{vlangsocrev}`

Output: Van Lange, Joireman et al. (2013)

I'd like for it to be just "Van Lange et. al (2013)".

EDIT

Adding minimal working example, and it's actually working.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[autostyle, style=croatian]{csquotes}
\usepackage[labelsep = period, labelfont = it, justification = 
 centering, skip = 8pt]{caption}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\addto\captionscroatian{\renewcommand{\bibname}{\Large\bfseries     Literatura}}

\renewcommand{\BCBT}{}%  comma between authors in ref. list when no. of
                  %%  authors = 2
\renewcommand{\BCBL}{}%  comma before last author when no. of authors > 2
\renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{i sur.\hbox{}}% ``and others''
\renewcommand{\BBAA}{i}
\renewcommand{\BBAB}{i}
\renewcommand{\BIn}{U:}
\renewcommand{\BED}{Ur.\hbox{}}
\renewcommand{\BEDS}{Ur.\hbox{}}
\renewcommand{\BPGS}{str.\hbox{}}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\itshape}{}{0pt}{}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalsize\itshape}

\titlespacing{\paragraph}{%
\parindent}{% left margin
  0.1\baselineskip}{% space before (vertical)
  1em}%               space after (horizontal)

\setlength{\bibhang}{1cm}

\begin{document}
\citet{vlangsocrev}

\citet{vlangsocrev}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}

{
\setstretch{1}
\bibliography{mwe.bib}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT 2:

I tried linking to the original .bib file, the one containing the full bibliography, and the MWE is still working fine.

EDIT 3:

Okay, the problem seems to appear when there are multiple citations from the same author and in the same year. Adding the following bibentry and citing caueses the problem.

```
@book{
    vancoop,
  title={Social dilemmas: The Psychology of Human Cooperation},
  author={Van Lange, Paul AM and Balliet, Daniel P and Parks, Craig D and Van
      Vugt, Mark},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Oxford University Press},
address = "New York, NY"
}
```

[image]

How can I replace this with 2013a and 2013b? The apacite texdoc says:

> If there are multiple citations with the same author and year, a letter should
>   be added to the year to distinguish the references. For example, one may refer
>   to two or more articles by J. Smith published in 1982. They should be referred
>   to as “Smith (1982a)”, “Smith (1982b)”, and so forth. To accomplish this, the
>   counter BibCnt is defined in apacite.sty. The \theBibCnt command defines
>   how the value of BibCnt is formatted. The default is “\alph{BibCnt}”, that  is,
>   as a plain lowercase letter.

But that doesn't seem  to happen. Any clues?

Comment: Please add a minimal working example. Which style do you use?

Comment: Hey, added the MWE. Rembemberd that I forgot it right after I posted, but wasn't able to edit earlier. Anyway, the MWE is working properly. I can't figure out why apacite is confused in the original file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read in a thread here somewhere that this is not a bug, but actually a fetaure.

The desired variant works perfectly fine if **all** authors are the same. But if it's just the first author, apacite prints the second one's name too.

For instance, when I copied the first bib entry, changed the key and the title, and then referenced it, everything worked perfectly fine.

So, the conclusion is that it's a feature and all's well.

I'm closing the question.